How to access external object parent record details in test class
As per this link https://salesforcemonday.com/2021/09/21/mocking-external-objects-and-code-coverage-with-examples/ to test external object we have to mock the records. test_samplecomp__Grant__c is child for externalobject test_samplecomp__Order__x and  test_samplecomp__Order__x is child for test_samplecomp__Auth__c  i created test record for test_samplecomp__Auth__c and mapped to external id field and its marked as external id.
when i test Auth name returns null. how to query external object parent field?
Here is my Apex class
public class Externalcontroller {
    public static void myMethod(){
        if(test.IsRunningtest()){
            List<test_samplecomp__Grant__c> mygrant =[select id,Name,test_samplecomp__External_Order__r.test_samplecomp__orderID__r.Name from test_samplecomp__Grant__c];
            System.debug('IsRunning'+mygrant);
        }
        
        List<test_samplecomp__Grant__c> mygrant =[select id,Name,test_samplecomp__External_Order__r.test_samplecomp__orderID__r.Name from test_samplecomp__Grant__c];
        
        for(test_samplecomp__Grant__c g:mygrant){
            String Name =g.test_samplecomp__External_Order__r.test_samplecomp__orderID__r.Name;
            System.debug('Name'+Name);
        }
      
    }
}

Mock class for external object
public virtual class ExternalObjectQuery
{
   public static List<SObject> records(List<SObject> records)
   {
      return instance.passThrough(records);
   }

   static ExternalObjectQuery instance = new ExternalObjectQuery();
   @TestVisible static void setMock(ExternalObjectQuery mock) { 
       instance = mock; 
   }

   protected virtual List<SObject> passThrough(List<SObject> records)
   {
      return records;
   }
}

Test class
@isTest
public class ExternalcontrollerTest {
       class Mock extends ExternalObjectQuery
  {
     final List<test_samplecomp__Order__x > externalRecords;
     Mock(List<test_samplecomp__Order__x > externalRecords)
     {
        this.externalRecords = externalRecords;
     }

     protected override List<SObject> passThrough(List<SObject> records)
     {
        return externalRecords;
     }
  }
    
    
    @isTest
    static void myMethod(){
        
     
        
        List<test_samplecomp__Order__x > mockRecords = new List<test_samplecomp__Order__x >();
        test_samplecomp__Order__x externaldata =new test_samplecomp__Order__x();
        externaldata.test_samplecomp__customerID__c='123';
        externaldata.test_samplecomp__orderID__c='123';
        mockRecords.add(externaldata);
        
        ExternalObjectQuery.setMock(new Mock(mockRecords));
        ExternalObjectQuery.records(mockRecords);
        
        test_samplecomp__Auth__c  Auth =new test_samplecomp__Auth__c();
        Auth.Name='Test AUth';
        Auth.test_samplecomp__Sub_Id__c=Decimal.valueOf(externaldata.test_samplecomp__orderID__c);
        Insert Auth;
        System.debug('Auth'+Auth);  
        
        test_samplecomp__Grant__c grantlinesummary =new test_samplecomp__Grant__c();
        System.debug('externaldata.test_samplecomp__orderID__c'+externaldata.test_samplecomp__orderID__c);
        grantlinesummary.test_samplecomp__External_Order__c=externaldata.test_samplecomp__orderID__c;
        grantlinesummary.Name='Test Grantline sumarry';
        insert grantlinesummary;    
        Test.startTest();
        Externalcontroller.myMethod();
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}

Expected output

Regards,
Afrose
